# How to save array of json in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the next issue:

I have the variables like this:

```
links: [{linkTo: "aaa", text: "bbb"}, {linkTo: "ccc", text: "ddd"}],
style: {
      color: "green",
      backgroundColor: "#dddddd",
      borderStyle: "solid",
      borderWidth: 4,
      borderColor: "#bbbbb",
      borderRadius: 10,
      hoverColor: "#aaaaa",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "red"
}
```

and I want to store them in the mongo DB inside **one** field called LinksTree (using mongoose).

I tried the following but didn't work (goes stright to the default):

```
    LinksTree: {
        links: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        },
        style: {
            type: Object,
            default: {
                color: "black",
                backgroundColor: "#dadada",
                borderStyle: "solid",
                borderWidth: 4,
                borderColor: "#dadada",
                borderRadius: 10,
                hoverColor: "#31941F",
                hoverBackgroundColor: "white"
            }
        }
    },
```

How can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) to update the database. Let's assume the model name is `Tree`.

```
const { Tree } = require('../models/tree');

Tree.findByIdAndUpdate({
    _id: req.body.treeId
}, {
    $set: {
        treeLinks: req.body.newTreeLinks
    }
}).then((doc) => {
    res.send(doc)
}, (e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

`newTreeLinks` would be the object matching the fields which would just replace the current one, saved in the database. Otherwise, it would create a brand new one.

In this case, your `Tree` model could look like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const Tree = new Schema({
    treeLinks: {
        links: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        },
        style: {
            type: Object,
            default: {
                color: "black",
                backgroundColor: "#dadada",
                borderStyle: "solid",
                borderWidth: 4,
                borderColor: "#dadada",
                borderRadius: 10,
                hoverColor: "#31941F",
                hoverBackgroundColor: "white"
            }
        }
    }
})

const Tree = mongoose.model('Tree', treeSchema)

module.exports = {
    Tree
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much ;) And what about the implemantion of the model? How is that supposed to look like?

Comment: Updated my answer with a full example. Please have a look.